# How to get the boot time of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, boot-time

I am trying to find the boot time of Ubuntu.

The following tells me that my last reboot took 1 minutes 39 second.

```
$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Wed Jan  8 14:55 - 16:35  (01:39)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Wed Jan  8 14:38 - 14:55  (00:16)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Wed Jan  8 14:27 - 14:38  (00:10)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Wed Jan  8 11:07 - 14:27  (03:19)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Wed Jan  8 00:03 - 00:31  (00:27)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Tue Jan  7 10:39 - 14:22  (03:43)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Mon Jan  6 10:51 - 18:42  (07:50)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Sun Jan  5 22:08 - 00:19  (02:11)    
reboot   system boot  3.8.0-29-generic Sat Jan  4 11:34 - 15:47  (04:12)
```

While when I looked at `dmesg`:

```
[   14.707210] type=1400 audit(1389173157.301:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

This shows that the total boot time is 14.707210. So as per the above two methods which is the actual boot time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command, `last reboot`, does not tell you the *boot time*. It tells you at what times your system was running. For example, the first entry tells you that your system has been running from 14:55 to 16:35 on Wed 8. That's 1 hour and 39 minutes. It did not take your system 1 hour and 39 minutes to boot - hopefully ;)

The second command, `dmesg`, brings you closer to what you want to know, but since `dmesg` will continually output more system events while your system is running, it's not the tool of choice to measure boot time either.

If you really want to reliably measure your system boot time, I would recommend a tool such as bootchart.

See here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the values mean, if you want faster loading times update to Ubuntu 13.10, you will see a nice speedup on your machine and all your apps updated to the latest stable versions.

Remember to run in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

(this erases packages you don't need)

You can also speed up your system by:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

and then

```
sudo bleachbit
```

This program will delete many unused temporary files, you will also see a nice boost on the loading times, please try it and post the new results so that we can all know the real speedup. Thank you, hope it works!

PS: your phone has a stopwatch function :)

Comment: The 1:39 means 1 hour 39 minutes, it's the time the system has been running (from 14:55 to 16:35, in other words from 2:55pm 'til 4:35pm on wednesday jan 8th.)